# React Semantic UI Modal is not Shown

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I'm trying to show a modal to the user using `react-semantic-ui`. Whenever I put the modal component under Navigation class it works well. Unfortunately, whenever I want to show the modal in `LoginRegistrationMenu` component it doesn't work properly and not even shown anything!

```
export default class Navigation extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      showMenu: false
    }
    this.showMenu = this.showMenu.bind(this)
    this.hideMenu = this.hideMenu.bind(this)
  }


  showMenu(){
    this.setState({
      showMenu: true
    })
    document.addEventListener('click', this.hideMenu)
  }

  hideMenu(){
    this.setState({
        showMenu: false
    })
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.hideMenu)
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="navigation-wrapper">
        <div className="navigation">      
            <div>
              <Link to='/needs'>
                <div>
                  needs
                </div>
              </Link>
            <div className="login-register" onClick={this.showMenu}>
              <Icon name="user circle" size='big' color={this.state.showMenu? 'red': 'black'} />
              {this.state.showMenu ? <LoginRegistrationMenu/> : null}
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class LoginRegistrationMenu extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="login-register-dialogue">
            <Modal
              trigger={<div>login</div>}
              header='Reminder!'
              content='Call Benjamin regarding the reports.'
              actions={['Snooze', { key: 'done', content: 'Done', positive: true }]}
            />
          <hr/>
          <a href="#">
            <div>sign up</div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

How can I change the above code to make it work well?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: @ravibagul91 no! :(

Comment: Are you getting `login` div?

Comment: Have you imported Modal, `import { Modal } from 'semantic-ui-react'`? Have you added `semantic.min.css`?

Comment: @ravibagul91 yeah I imported everything, as I said I catch no error. I get the login div, too.

Answer (score 1):

**Considering you have imported everything, and added `semantic.min.css` correctly.**

I think the problem is here,

```
<div className="login-register" onClick={this.showMenu}>
    <Icon name="user circle" size='big' color={this.state.showMenu? 'red': 'black'} />
    {this.state.showMenu ? <LoginRegistrationMenu/> : null}  //problem line
</div>
```

You have added, `LoginRegistrationMenu` component inside the `div` on which you have written `onClick` event. So cliking on `login` div will not show `Modal`, but call `showMenu` function again. You need to do this,

```
<div className="login-register" onClick={this.showMenu}>
    <Icon name="user circle" size='big' color={this.state.showMenu? 'red': 'black'} />
</div>

{this.state.showMenu ? <LoginRegistrationMenu/> : null}  //Keep this outside of div
```

Another thing is, you don't do this,

```
document.addEventListener('click', this.hideMenu)
```

It's default behaviour that, When `Modal` is open and you click outside of `Modal` it will get close.

If you want toggle functionality here,

```
<div className="login-register" onClick={this.showMenu}>
    <Icon name="user circle" size='big' color={this.state.showMenu? 'red': 'black'} />
</div>
```

I suggest you to do this,

```
<div className="login-register" onClick={this.toggleMenu}>
    <Icon name="user circle" size='big' color={this.state.showMenu? 'red': 'black'} />
</div>
```

And your `toggleMenu` function should be,

```
toggleMenu(){
  this.setState({
    showMenu: !this.state.showMenu
  })
}
```

Now clicking on the same `Icon` will toggle your menu.

Comment: I haven't access to my laptop right now! I will test it in 5 hours. Thanks